# How to Find Week number, Period and year from Date in Redshift? (Week Starting with Wednesday and ends up with Tuesday)

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Need to find `weekNumber` like `1,2,3,4` but the week starts with Wednesday and ends with Tuesday from date column and after the 4th week, again the week restart by again as the 1st week and so on (no need to consider month).

Need to find the `Period` based on `weekNumber` only, 4 weeks as 1 Period and Periods end with 13 (period 1-13) will restart again 1st period. 
(4 weeks = 1 period) (no need to consider month).

Now need to calculate the `businessyear` based on `Period`. 13 Periods as One `businessyear`. (13 periods = 1 year)

Calculation logic:

- 7 days * 4 weeks = 28 days = 1 period
- 13 periods = 1 businessyear

Example:

- A year has 365 days normally
- In my scenario, 4 weeks * 7 days = 28 days
- 28 days *13 periods =   364 days
- The remaining days will come as the 5th week and period 14.

```
Datekey   date        Year  semistor  Quarter  Month       DayName     DayNum  Wnumber
20090101  01-01-2009  2009  1         1        January  1   Thursday   1       0
20090102  02-01-2009  2009  1         1        January  1   Friday     2       0
20090103  03-01-2009  2009  1         1        January  1   Saturday   3       0
20090104  04-01-2009  2009  1         1        January  1   Sunday     0     
20090105  05-01-2009  2009  1         1        January  1   Monday     0     
20090106  06-01-2009  2009  1         1        January  1   Tuesday    6       0
20090107  07-01-2009  2009  1         1        January  1   Wednesday  0       0
20090108  08-01-2009  2009  1         1        January  1   Thursday   1       1
20090109  09-01-2009  2009  1         1        January  1   Friday     2       1
20090110  10-01-2009  2009  1         1        January  1   Saturday   3       1
20090111  11-01-2009  2009  1         1        January  1   Sunday     4       1
20090112  12-01-2009  2009  1         1        January  1   Monday     5       1
20090113  13-01-2009  2009  1         1        January  1   Tuesday    6       1
20090114  14-01-2009  2009  1         1        January  1   Wednesday  0       1
```

No need to consider the month in my scenario, need to consider leap year also (2016, 2020).

Answer (score 0):

The traditional way to do this type of thing is to **create a calendar table** in the database. Then, your queries can simply `JOIN` to the calendar table to extract the relevant value.

I find that **the easiest way to create the `calendar` table is to use Excel**. Simply write some formulas that provide the desired values and Copy Down for the next decade or so. Then, save the sheet as CSV and load it into the database.

This way, you can totally avoid complex calculations involving database functions and you can use whatever rules you wish.